# Changing classname of a specific element on click from a mapped array an keeping the same classname until clicked again in react

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
const allTodos = [{id: 1, name: 'whatever user type'}, { }, { }, .... { }] // Defined as an array using setState in other file. Imported in this file as allTodos using props.

export const Todos = (props) => {

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

props.allTodos.map((prev) => {
return (

<div id="item_container">

<button type='button' className = `check_button ${prev.id === index ? 'checked' : 'not_checked'}`
onClick = {() => setIndex(prev.id)}>

<img src = {check} alt="" id = "check_img"></img>

</button>

<li id="li_item">{prev.name}</li>
</div>

)}
}
```

Explanation : Here, I set up a const `index` using `useState` that wiil change its value to the id of the element clicked upon in order to change the `className` of that element.

Question : Now, I succeeded in doing that but everytime I click on other element, the `className` gets added to that element but gets removed from the previous element it was added upon. Now I want to somehow preserve the `className` to those every elements I click on until I click on them again to change their `className`. By the way the styling that I desire to change is the `background` of that button/element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to keep track of *every* index that's checked - for this you'll need an array (or a number you do bit calculations with). A stateful `index` number doesn't contain enough information.

```js
const allTodos = [{ id: 1, name: 'whatever user type' }, { id: 2, name: 'foo' }];

const Todos = ({ allTodos }) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState(() => allTodos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, checked: false })));
    const handleClick = (i) => () => {
      setTodos(todos.map((todo, j) => j !== i ? todo : ({ ...todo, checked: !todo.checked })))
    };
    return todos.map(({ id, name, checked }, i) => (
        <div id="item_container">
            <button
                type='button'
                className={`check_button ${checked ? 'checked' : 'not_checked'}`}
                onClick={handleClick(i)}
            >
                <img alt="" id="check_img"></img>
            </button>
            <div>{name}</div>
        </div >
    ))
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todos allTodos={allTodos} />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.checked {
  background-color: green;
}
.not_checked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

You also need:

- When not using plain `'` `"` quotes, use `{}` delimiters around the prop
- `<li>`s should only be children of `<ul>`s
- Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML
- You need to return the mapped JSX from the `Todos` component
- You are missing a `)` at the end of `allTodos.map`

Comment: May I know if " j " is used as an argument here ? If yes, then what is it getting as parameter?

Comment: Yes, the second argument to the `.map` callback is the index being iterated over. First iteration, it'll be 0, second iteration it'll be 1, etc. It's used to determine the changed index in the todos array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use array to save ids clicked and removed id from array when clicked again.

```
const [idList, setIdList] = useState([])

const handleClick=(id, checked) => {
  if(checked){
    setIdList.filter(item => item !== id)
  } else {
    setIdList([...idList, id])
  }
}

props.allTodos.map((prev) => {
   const checked = idList.includes(prev.id)
   ...  
   className ={`check_button ${checked ? 'checked' : 'not_checked'}`}
   onClick = {() => handleClick(prev.id, checked)
   ...
```